# Ora2Pg not working properly

Tags: oracle, postgresql, data-migration

I am using ora2pg to migrate my data from oracle to postgres database. As an initial step I am exporting schema. I found that the generated sql file has many errors like duplicate sql statements, duplicate parameters in functions, which fail while the sql is executed. i am trying to manually correct these errors in the generated sql file. Is there a better way or to avoid this error in sql file.
Actually I just need to transfer data from oracle to postgres database. But don't know if its possible.
I am using Ora2Pg 15.3 and my postgres version is 8.4. I am using a spatial database.

Thanks

Comment: Postgres 8.4 is no longer supported or maintained. Why are you migrating to such an outdated version _today_? If you want any answer to your question you should show us the original Oracle DDL, the generated statements for Postgres and your complete configuration for Ora2Pg. When I was using Ora2Pg, I had no such problems.

Comment: If you are transferring *data only*, you can probably export CSV, then import into PostgreSQL with `COPY`. Though this may not work with geographic data. Another option would be an ETL tool. All horse's points are entirely valid, though ... most notably the version. 8.4. Why?

Comment: See the problem is that the sql file that is generated has these errors. So till this point postgres is out of picture. I can probably use a newer version. But till this point only ora2pg 15.3 (latest) and oracle instant client 12.1 are  involved.

Comment: till this point only ora2pg 15.3 (latest), oracle instant client 12.1 (to provide the oracle libs to Dbd:oracle perl module) and oracle 11g database are  involved. So don't know why errors like : ALTER TABLE assetentry ADD PRIMARY KEY (entryid);
ALTER TABLE assetentry ADD PRIMARY KEY (entryid); //repeated statements  or CREATE INDEX ix_35e3e7c6 ON company (system,system); 
CREATE INDEX ix_38efe3fd ON company (logoid,logoid); //system and logoid repeated are occurring in the generated sql file.

Comment: Addtionally in the conf file, I have just provided the DSN. The export type is TABLE. I plan to change it to TABLE,PACKAGE,VIEW, COPY, GRANT,SEQUENCE,TRIGGER,FUNCTION,PROCEDURE,TABLESPACE,TYPE,PARTITION,FDW,MVIEW,QUERY to get everything from the oracle database.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to upgrade your postgresql. 
With version 9.1 of postgresql and `Ora2Pg 17.5` version everything works properly. 
But remember to install the version of `DBI-1636` or later, `DBD-Oracle-1.74` or later, `DBD-Pg-3.5.3` or later. 
Furthermore, you install the oracle client,

```
oracle-instantclient12.1-sqlplus-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm
oracle-instantclient12.1-basic-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm
oracle-instantclient12.1-devel-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm
```

for example.

and set the right path

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/
```